# how do i implement emojicon keyboard view into system keyboard

Tags: android, textview, emoji

How do I implement emojiconKeyboard+AlphanumericKeyboard in my Android application.

My application developing in Android, iPhone and PHP. so JSON through I receive data so how I render unicode character to emojicon and display on TextView.

In EditTextbox I can add emoji with text.

Comment: Yes this is how you should do render unicode character to emojicon. What is an issue ?

Comment: how i render unicode charcter to emojicon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got answer regarding to custom keyboard. I can create custom soft keyboard and emoji keyboard using Input Method Service. i have already publish my custom keyboard app.

if any one want to create custom keyboard here is the tutorial link.

https://www.androidauthority.com/lets-build-custom-keyboard-android-832362/

and for emoji keyboard i integrate this library.

https://github.com/ankushsachdeva/emojicon

Answer (score 0):

Android `textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("UNICODE_CHAR_HERE");`

iOS `label.text = @"UNICODE_CHAR_HERE";`